# checkbox onclick event jquery not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a website that has a few dynamic boxes on. Every 15 seconds my javascript fires some ajax requests and then outputs the json replies on the page which works great. My issue is with my checkbox toggle thing.

I had the on change event hooked up to a php page that would check the value and if its a 1 change to 0 and if 0 change to 1 (this controls the checkbox checked value).

My issue is when I change it on another window ... it will after 15 seconds update and move to the state I change it to ... but this will then trigger the onchange event and I get a loop.

I need to use the onClick event to only change when it is manually clicked and not when it is automatically changed by the script.

How do I do this as onClick isnt working :/

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.on_off :checkbox').iphoneStyle();
  $('.disabled :checkbox').iphoneStyle();
  $('.css_sized_container :checkbox').iphoneStyle({ 
     resizeContainer: false, 
     resizeHandle: false 
    });
  $('.long_tiny :checkbox').iphoneStyle({ 
     checkedLabel: 'Very Long Text',
     uncheckedLabel: 'Tiny' 
    });

  var onchange_checkbox = ($('.onchange :checkbox')).iphoneStyle({
    onClick: function(elem, value) { 
     Update();
    }
  });


function Update(){
  $( "#result" ).load( "change.php");
}
</script>
```

Comment: You are missing `});` to close the load function

Comment: don't space between your class names and `:checkbox`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are a couple of issues with the script posted. Could you see if this helps?

```
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">

    $(window).load(function() {

        $('.on_off:checkbox').iphoneStyle();
        $('.disabled:checkbox').iphoneStyle();
        $('.css_sized_container:checkbox').iphoneStyle({ 
            resizeContainer: false, 
            resizeHandle: false 
        });
        $('.long_tiny:checkbox').iphoneStyle({ 
            checkedLabel: 'Very Long Text',
            uncheckedLabel: 'Tiny' 
        });

        var onchange_checkbox = ($('.onchange:checkbox')).iphoneStyle({
            onClick: function(elem, value) { 
                Update();
            }
        });

    });

    function Update(){
        $("#result").load("change.php");
    }

</script>
```

Comment: The script I posted is only part of my full code so the brackets do end correctly. It wont work with Click, maybe because of the iphone style plugin I have ... it only seems to work with on change. but then I end up stuck in a loop

Comment: I was thinking on change I would get the status of the checkbox and send it to my change.php with ajax ... if the value in the database = the value sent with ajax then leave it as is ... else change the database which will then update the page ... then it will again trigger the onchange event but this time the box == database so it will end .... How do I get the status ?

Answer (score 0):

try capturing the click event on the parent -

```
var onchange_checkbox = ($('.onchange :checkbox')).iphoneStyle();
onchange_checkbox.parent()[0].click(function(e){Update();});
```